# How do I .htaccess to hide the subfolder from url?

Tags: regex, .htaccess, web

my directory

```
/main 
      index.php
      /projects 
                /project111
                /project222
```

Example

Sample old domain : http://www.website.com/projects/projectname

Sample new domain : http://www.website.com/projectname

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/projects
RewriteRule ^/projects/(.*)$ /$1 [L]
```

help me please.

Comment: What have you attempted? Post anything you have tried, that will allow us to better assist you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In

```
http://www.website.com/projects/.htaccess
```

add the following lines:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule (.*)/?$ http://www.website.com/$1 [R=301]
```

`()` is a capture group

`.` is any character (except newline)

`*` is the preceding character 0 to any number of times

`?` is the preceding character 0 to 1 times

`$` is end of match

`$1` returns the first capture group

So... the last line above will capture all the characters after `http://www.website.com/projects/` (including or omitting a trailing slash) and redirect the browser to `http://www.website.com/` followed by the same series of characters.

Answer (score 0):

Use mod_rewrite and perform a replacement in the .htaccess..

Although wouldn't it be cleaner to simply move the folder ?